# IE7 label positioning problem, problem with the div width

Tags: css

I have problem with labels inside a `fieldset` (feedback form). It is correctly shown in Firefox, Opera, IE6, but it looks ugly in IE7 [See this page here](http://www.partnergrp.ru/consult.htm).
You can also find `pg.css` (main ccs file), `ie6.css`, `ie.css`.

HTML code:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Вы можете отправить нам вопрос прямо с этой страницы, заполнив форму</legend>
    <form action="mail.php" method="post">
        <label for="name">Имя*</label> <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        <label for="tel">Телефон</label> <input type="text" name="tel"><br>
        <label for="email">E-mail*</label> <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        <label for="title">Тема вопроса</label> <input type="text" name="title"><br>
        <label for="mess">Вопрос*</label><textarea name="mess"></textarea><br>
        <label for="submit">&nbsp </label><input type="submit" value="Отправить" name="submit" class="button"><br>
        <label for="reset">&nbsp </label><input type="reset" value="Очистить" class="button"> 
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

CSS code:

```
label {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    text-align:right;
    margin-right:5px;
}

textarea {
    width: 400px;
    height:200px;
    font-size: 110%;
}

input, textarea {
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 5px;
    border:1px #7a974d solid;
    background: #f1ece8;
}
```

The second problem is that the brown line in IE7 is not the 100% of the main div's width.

```
#text, #text1 {
    border-top: 3px solid #4d320f;/*brown line*/
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1em 0 1em;
    padding: 7px 0 0 0;
}
```

It seems to me, that div=text is not the same width as `div=container` and the upper div with logo and menu (div=maincontent). The width of `div=text` depends on the largest paragraph. On my page the width of div=text is the same as the last paragraph in the bottom of the page, so the brown line is the same width:

```
<p class="bottom">&copy; Copyright <a href="http://www.pg.ru/contact.htm">«ПартнерГрупп»</a>.  Москва, ул. Давыдковская, д. 12, стр.7, <b>(495) 725-14-09</b></p>
```

The `width:100%` doesn't help. I can't figure out what can be wrong. I'm not a specialist in css and I need your help.

Answer (score 3):

After looking at your code, the problem seems to occur higher up in your CSS.  In pg/pg.css there's block of code that looks like the following:

```
#maincontent {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

If you take out the float:left; everything will begin to line up correctly in IE7.